# Ability to pass variables through add to cart url and query them at time of checkout?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been having difficulty trying to accomplish the passing of variables that a user inputs from within the product page into the cart so that when the user checks out I can utilize that data.

I'm confused on whether I should be using custom fields / variables / or some other means to make this work. I'll try to describe the exact workflow before so my use case is clear.

1) User lands on a specific simple product page

2) Before the user can click the add to cart button, they must validate their account credentials from my auth server that is decoupled from wordpress.

3) Once the details are validated the user can click add to cart and the product in the cart would have the user details attached to it in some form for querying at checkout.

4) * At this point user interaction is done

5) * At time of checkout I've hooked add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'order_system' ); to inspect the cart and the items within the cart

6) *** **I need to retrieve the variables that were passed along with the item*** **

7) ** My checkout hook then POSTs the referenced variables to an API **

Any help is greatly appreciated, I've struggled with this for some time now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [guide](http://www.xatik.com/2013/02/06/add-custom-form-woocommerce-product/) I wrote is probably perfect for what you need.  This plugin is different, but it should have all of the hooks and info you need to modify it for your own needs.

I show all of the steps on adding a custom form and adding the values the user enters to the cart meta so you can query it out during the checkout process.

```
function is_xaik_wc_in_cart() {
    global $woocommerce;
    if (sizeof($woocommerce->cart->get_cart())>0) :
        foreach ($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $item_id => $values) :
            if (isset($values['_xatik_wc_data'])) :
                return TRUE;
            endif;
        endforeach;
    endif;

    return FALSE;
}
```

Once you know it's in the cart, you can just query it doing another foreach loop on the cart. Or just modify the function to do it all at once.

All of these variables should stick with the cart meta information.

**Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/DirtyRasa/82e774ced938e9e3260c) example that should work.**

Comment: I was already reading your guide when you answered this! Thanks a ton for the assistance, I think I'm on the right track with your advice. I'm trying to figure out exactly which filters and hooks I need to implement now. Basically I want to add a user and password onto the item during the add to cart process so I can query it on checkout.

Comment: You can probably use the same hooks I use for the Font Size.

Comment: Which exactly would those be? I'm having trouble figuring out when exactly each filter is fired and what I could exclude from the code

Comment: I think I may just need:add_filter('woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', array(&$this, 'xatik_wc_get_cart_item_from_session'), 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item', array(&$this, 'xatik_wc_add_cart_item'), 10, 1);

Comment: You'll want to hook these functions to save the meta data and retrieve it:

woocommerce_add_cart_item_data and woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session

--edit, hit enter too soon instead of shift+enter

Comment: Oops I can't see which hooks you pasted :)

Comment: I only used the 'woocommerce_add_cart_item' filter to modify the price.  You shouldn't need to filter that function.

Comment: Could you post example code in a gist perhaps of how I would add 'username' and 'pass' onto the item? I'm having a tough time clicking this together in my head. I'd be grateful to the fullest extent and forever in your debt!

Comment: You can try this:  [link](https://gist.github.com/DirtyRasa/82e774ced938e9e3260c)  That should get you to where you need.  If this helped, please mark my solution as the answer.

Comment: Craig you are a life saver, thank you a ton. How do I pass the data into these functions? For instance say I have an input field on the product page that the user filled in, when I click add to cart how do I take the value of that field and pass it into the function? Thank you so much

Comment: Your inputs need to be part of the 'add to cart' button so when you do hit 'add to cart' it will be in the _POST data.  Please don't forget to mark the solution as an answer.

Comment: Understood! Thank you very much Craig, marked as the solution!

Comment: Craig can you help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053365/persisting-meta-data-on-item-and-retrieving-at-checkout-complete I'm unable to get the final step working! Thank you for everything, Nick

Answer (score 0):

On a shopping cart your main objective is to make the shopping as easy as possible, so you should NOT use java script variables or custom hidden fields (i am assuming you were talking about these), if you do so those variables will be lost if the user exit of your website or he just hit back after adding something to the car.

Try using cookies or sessions.

You can find information about cookies [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp)

Comment: The goal is to make a user validate their inputs prior to the item being added to the cart. Then after a successful confirmation those values get set to attributes on the item so I can use them at the time of checkout to make additional API calls