# Persisting meta data on item, and retrieving at checkout complete

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm attempting to set meta data on an item when it's added to the cart, persist it through each page reload and when checkout is successful retrieve the meta data to pass to a seperate API.

The below code is successful in the ense that it echos the meta data after a page reload so I'm considering that to be a success.

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'order_system');
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'nick_add_cart_item_data', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', 'nick_get_cart_item_from_session', 10, 2);

function nick_add_cart_item_data($cart_item_meta, $product_id) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $nick_form_data = get_post_meta($product_id, '_nick_form_data', true);

    $cart_item_meta['_nick_form_data'] = $nick_form_data;
    $cart_item_meta['_nick_credential_data']['username'] = ( isset( $_POST['username'] ) && $_POST['username'] != '') ? $_POST['username'] : '';
    $cart_item_meta['_nick_credential_data']['password'] = ( isset( $_POST['password'] ) && $_POST['password'] != '') ? $_POST['password'] : '';

    return $cart_item_meta;
}

function nick_get_cart_item_from_session($cart_item, $values) {

if (isset($values['_nick_form_data'])) {
        $cart_item['_nick_form_data'] = $values['_nick_form_data'];
    }

    if (isset($values['_nick_credential_data'])) {
        $cart_item['_nick_credential_data'] = $values['_nick_credential_data'];
    echo $values['_nick_credential_data']['username'] . $values['_nick_credential_data']['password'] ;
    }

    return $cart_item;
}
```

When I call this function, which fires when the order is completed I'm unable to retain any of the item meta data.

```
function order_system($order_id)
{
global $woocommerce;

try {
    // do something that can go wrong
    // instantiate new order from WooCommerce
    $order  = new WC_Order($order_id);
    $userid = $order->user_id;

foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $values) :  
                if (isset($values['_nick_form_data'])) :
// Not getting inside this case statement
                endif;
    endforeach;
....
```

I'm unsure of what I'm doing wrong, any help is appreciated. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

It's a little late, but: although you're attaching your metadata to the *cart* items, they're not subsequently being added to the *order* items when the order is created. To do that:

```
function nick_add_order_item_meta($itemID, $values) {

    $nick_form_data = $values['_nick_form_data'];

    if (!empty($nick_form_data)) {
        wc_add_order_item_meta($itemID, '_nick_form_data', $nick_form_data);
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_add_order_item_meta','nick_add_order_item_meta', 1, 2);
```

At the point your order is created, your cart item meta `_nick_form_data` will be attached to each item. You'll then be able to see it in the backend of WooCommerce when viewing an order: each order item should have a **`[?]`** next to it which will show you the attached metadata.

Comment: Thanks, this answer saved me

Comment: "A little late" has never been so much an euphemism :D :D

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are hooking in too late with the 'order_system' function.

Try hooking in to here instead:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', array(&$this, 'nick_checkout_field_process') );
function nick_checkout_field_process() {
global $woocommerce;

try {
// do something that can go wrong
// instantiate new order from WooCommerce
$order  = new WC_Order($order_id);
$userid = $order->user_id;

foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $values) :  
            if (isset($values['_nick_form_data'])) :
                // Do Something here
                // echo $values['_nick_credential_data']['username'] . $values['_nick_credential_data']['password'] ;
            endif;
endforeach;
....
```